# Ignore a java class file

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Is there a way, either in the Android Studio IDE or in code to ignore an entire class file, errors and all? I have a class that I no longer need but am not just yet ready to delete it - but it has errors so I cant run my project until those are fixed. So I don't need to compile it, I just want to keep it handy in my project in case I need to go back to it and grab a piece of code.

Comment: Put `/*` at the top and `*/` at the bottom? Comment out everything but the class declaration itself and the errors should go away...

Comment: you can use git , and I do like @Takendarkk said, just sometimes...

Comment: The problem with commenting is that if you have actual comments; when you uncomment you lose your original comments and cause more problems than you started with.

Comment: Just rename it so that its name ends with something else than `.java` ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you try renaming the file from `.java`? Such as .txt or similar

Also if you just add `/*` and `*/` at the start and end of the file, so that everything is commented out, and it'll be easy to remove the comment

Comment: Renaming the extension seems to be the best option. Do you know if its possible to show the .java file extension in the project panel? All other file types have their appropriate extensions...

Comment: Hmmm I'm not sure. I would assume all of the classes without .java in the project panel would have that extension

Answer (score 1):

You are not ready to comment the entire code ?

**Cntrl+A**

**Cntrl+Shift+"?"**

Comment: The auto comment-er works great, but uncommenting seems to be an issue if you have actual comments in your code.

Answer (score 0):

you can comment the all class with 2 steps

1) select all class by **Ctrl+A**

2) comment the selected section by **Ctrl+Shift+/**

Answer (score 0):

Renaming the .java file to something else as advised above should suffice your issue. However, if you have inherited this class elsewhere, there would be compilation errors.

Answer (score -3):

You can add @deprecated in the comment above the class declaration. IntelliJ project structure will put a line through the name